# How to return Mutablelivedata hashmap from Viewmodel

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, mvvm

I have declared the MutableLivedata hashmap
 `lateinit var latestMessageMapdata : MutableLiveData<HashMap<String,ChatMessage>>`

I am trying to return the hashmap from the below code

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/XXXXXXX/$fromId")

        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d(LatestMessagesActivity.TAG, "database error: " + databaseError.message)
            }

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                Log.d(LatestMessagesActivity.TAG, "has children: " + dataSnapshot.hasChildren())
                if (!dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                   isRefreshing.postValue(false)
                }
            }

        })


        ref.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            }

            override fun onChildMoved(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
            }

            override fun onChildChanged(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage::class.java)?.let {
                    //LatestMessageViewModel.latestMessagesMap[dataSnapshot.key!!] = it
                  latestMessageMapdata[dataSnapshot.key!!]?.postValue(it)
                 //   refreshRecyclerViewMessages()
                }
            }

            override fun onChildAdded(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage::class.java)?.let {
                   // latestMessagesMap[dataSnapshot.key!!] = it
                    
                     latestMessageMapdata[dataSnapshot.key!!]?.postValue(it)
                    //LatestMessageViewModel.latestMessageMapdata. = it
                  
                }
            }

            override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            }

        })
```

But I am getting

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
```

public operator fun MatchGroupCollection.get(name: String): MatchGroup? defined in kotlin.text

Please help me out with this as I am beginner in kotlin and MVVM

Answer (score 1):

It is a livedata of type `HashMap<String, ChatMessage>`

So you should be creating an hashmap with the given key, value pair and then pass the value to the livedata.

For example,

```
val chatMessageMap = HashMap<String, ChatMessage>()
chatMessageMap[key] = value
lastMessageMapData.postValue(chatMessageMap)
```